# CocoaPods: use local pod written in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to use a Swift proj. as local pod in other Swift proj.

My pod is only one swift file with UIImageView extension:

```
//
// UIImageView+loader.swift
//

import UIKit

extension UIImageView {

    func loadWithUrlString(urlString: String) {
        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        if url != nil {
            self.loadWithUrl(url!)
        }
    }

    func loadWithUrl(url : NSURL) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            println("response")
        })
    }
}
```

My Podfile:

```
# Podfile
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'WSImageLoader', :path=>'~/untitled folder/WSImageLoader'

use_frameworks!
```

My ViewController

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import WSImageLoader

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // does not work here ('UIImageView' does not have a member named 'loadWithUrl')
        self.imageView.loadWithUrl("http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/iw/down.ico")
    }
}
```

[image: Project Screenshot]

Pod install and compile proj. works, but how to use 
**loadWithUrl** from pod?

```
pod --version
0.36.0
```

Podspec

```
# WSImageLoader.podspec
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "WSImageLoader"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A short description of WSImageLoader."
  s.description  = ""
  s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/WSImageLoader"
  s.license      = "MIT (example)"
  s.author             = { "" => "" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "http://EXAMPLE/WSImageLoader.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }
  s.source_files  = "WSImageLoader/Classes/**/*.{swift}"
  s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

  s.public_header_files = "Classes/**/*.swift"

end
```

Comment: Are you managed to solve this? I got the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a extension in swift. Swift files are not currently supported in swift as also discussed here : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2218

So to use that extension file written in swift(UIImageView+loader.swift) just write it in objective c and the below process would help u to access the function.

You have to import the header files from the Local Pods.This Tutorial helped me to successfully import other Pods file.

https://medium.com/@kirualex/cocoapods-with-swift-e6f8ba8f0afc

Hope this help u as well.

Comment: I don't have any header files.

Comment: header files means UIImageView+loader.swift. Import this file into your header file as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: In tutorial they use pods written in ObjC.

Comment: but u can work same with swift and include the swift file ? have u tried including it

Comment: I only can do this: import WSImageLoader, because it's a framework in my pod proj. (See Screenshot). I can't do this: import UIImageView+loader.swift

Comment: currrently accessing swift file into cocoapods is not available so u have to write the extension into objective c as category and can use it by importing those files from bridge header.

Comment: should be supported since cocoa pod 0.36, see here: http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73343/discussion-between-dheeraj-singh-and-iosfleer).